# Installing Green Shoes on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shoes

I am trying to install "green_shoes" on a MacBook. Every time that I try to install the gem ('gem install green_shoes') I get an error:

> Failed to build gem native extension

Ruby 2.0 is installed on the machine. What am I missing?

Comment: I just installed fine. Where does it stop? Which of its dependencies are not being installed? Make sure that you have the required libraries installed on your machine.

Comment: puts stacktrace your  error after `'Failed to build gen native extension'`

Comment: is there a config.log file or anything else that you can show?

Comment: Yes, that was it! I was missing some dependencies: https://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes/wiki/Building-Green-Shoes-on-OSX